# ionic and apache2 incompatibility

Tags: php, debugging, ionic-framework, apache2, incompatibility

I've installed Ionic and Cordova, some days ago. And from this moment my php don't work any more on my local server.

Did it already happen to anyone else ?

[I have this kind of result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8Fjm.png)

If anyone can help me i'll be very gratefull !
 Ask me for any things you'ld need.

Thanks you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: I've tried the possibilities, but it didn't worked !..